# fatal error: 'ext/hash_map.h' file not found on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, stl, g++

I run some downloaded code using hash_map.h.  But when I compile it using g++, it gives error message:

fatal error: 'hash_map.h' file not found

I search on google, some one suggests to replace 'hash_map.h' by 'ext/hash_map.h' and add 'using namespace __gnu_cxx;'.  But still I get the error message 'fatal error: 'ext/hash_map.h' file not found'.

I type "sudo find / -name hash_map.h" in the terminal of my Mac, and get the following results.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/hash_map.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/hash_map.h
```

How to link hash_map.h to the downloaded code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the path to the hash_map.h to the Makefile as follows.

g++ -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ -c target.cpp

And I replace 'hash_map.h' by 'debug/hash_map.h', and add 'using namespace __gnu_cxx;'.

It works for me.